# How to mount a docker container so that I can run python scripts, which are stored in the inside of the container

Tags: python, docker, intellij-idea, ros, mount

I am using a [docker image](https://cloud.docker.com/u/alexanderpakakis/repository/docker/alexanderpakakis/deep_roboy_control_docker) (not mine) created through this [dockerfile](https://github.com/Roboy/DeepAndReinforced/blob/9d266456f2d45de737bf82f746ab8fec6ec0f0dd/docker_ws/Dockerfile).

ROS kinetic, ROS2 and some important packages are already installed on this image.
When I run the docker image with `docker run -it <image-hash-code>` ROS kinetic is working well and the packages, like gym, can be found by python3.
So, all in all the docker image is a great starting point for my own project.

However, I would like to change the python scripts, which are stored on the docker image. The python scripts are using the installed packages and are interacting with ROS kinetic as well as with ROS2.

I do not want to install on my Ubuntu system all these programs and packages, which are already installed on the docker image in order to test my own python scripts.

Is there a way to mount the docker image so that I can test my python scripts?
Of course, I can use vim to edit python scripts, but I am thinking more of IntelliJ.

So, how can an IDE (e.g. IntelliJ) access and run a python script, which is stored on the docker image, with the same result as I would execute this script  directly on the running container.

The method by Lord Johar, mounting the docker, edit the scripts with an IDE, save the image and then to run the image, is working, but is not what I would like to achieve.

My goal is to use the docker container as a development environment on which an IDE has access to and can use the installed programs and packages.

In other words: I would like to use an IDE on my host system in order to test my python scripts in the same way as the IDE would be installed on the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `docker commit`

1. use this command `docker commit <your python container>`.
2. Now type `docker images` to see the image.
3. You should rename and tag image like this command `docker tag myphthon:v1 <image ID>`
4. use docker run command and then enjoy your code.
   It's better to mount a volume to your container to persist your code and data [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag).

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would like to change the python scripts, which are stored on the docker image. The python scripts are using the installed packages and are interacting with ROS kinetic as well as with ROS2.

1. you must mount volume to your docker and edit your file.
2. better way is make your image
   install docker on your ubuntu, pull python image, use Dockerfile to create your image, every time you change your code build  new image by new tag then run image and enjoy docker container

---

In second way

1. Copy your python app to /path/to/your/app (My main file is index.py)
2. Change your directory to /path/to/your/app
3. Create a file with name `Dockerfile` :

   ```
   FROM python:alpine3.7
   COPY . /app
   WORKDIR /app
   RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
   EXPOSE 5000
   CMD python ./index.py
   ```

   Also note is the RUN directive that is calling PyPi (pip) and pointing to the requirements.txt file. This file contains a list of the dependencies that the application needs to run.
4. Build Your Image.

   ```
   docker build --tag my-app .
   ```

   Note: at the end of command is a dot, that is too important. another thing is you must be at /path/to/your/app inside Dockerfile
5. now you can run your container

   ```
   docker run --name python-app -p 5000:5000 my-app
   ```

Comment: Hello Lord Johar,
thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, you did not answer my question.

I would like to access the python scripts, which are stored in a docker image, with an IDE on my host system, like IntelliJ, and run these scripts.

Comment: if your container have mount volume, you have access to your scripts. and if do not mount a volume you do not have access.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean and how this should help me.

Comment: Docker has a option that can persist docker container date to host machine. if you want to have access to docker date you must add (mount) volume to docker. In second way I explain all you need, your IDE like IntelliJ or Pycharm and etc can connect to your host machine and your machine is connect to your docker container, So you can change your code inside container.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a tooling which can communicate with a local or remote docker demon.

I know that eclipse can do that. The tooling for this is called `Docker Tooling`. It can explore docker images and containers on a machine running a docker demon in your network. It can start and stop containers, commit containers to images and create images.

What you require (as I understand) is the ability to commit containers, since you are asking for changing scripts inside your container. If you like to persist your work on those docker containers, committing is indispensable.

Since I am not familiar wit IntelliJ, I would suggest to have a look onto the [eclipse's docker tooling wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Docker_Tooling) to get a clue whether it is what you are looking for. And then after you got an idea, look for analogies in your favorite IDE like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html#interacting-with-containers).

Another IDE which supports docker exploring is [clion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/01/using-docker-with-clion/)